# Cookie sent by backend disappears when page is refreshed and can't be accessed through document.cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, cookies

I recently built my first full-stack website as a pet project. The website worked fine when I was running it locally but when I deployed it, user authentication started breaking. What should happen in the website when a user successfully registers or logs in to the website, the server should send a cookie called auth-token which is a JSON web token(JWT). The auth-token contains user information that is decoded in the front end and based on the user info, the UI updates itself to show that a user is signed in.

As background info, the frontend is hosted on Netlify, and the backend is on the railway. The backend is built with Express and frontend with React.

The problem with the deployed version of my website is that when I enter the correct credentials for a test user, I get an alert message saying that the login was successful. The response shows up with a status code of 200. However, the front end fails to retrieve the cookie and update the UI. I looked in Chrome dev tools to see if the cookie was actually received. There is indeed a cookie called auth-token under the application tab. But when I try to access the cookie through "document. cookie" on the console, it returns an empty string. And when I refresh, all the cookies disappear from my website.

I'm guessing my frontend is failing right now because it uses document.cookie to find the cookie it's looking for and since the result of document.cookie is an empty string, it can't actually do anything with it.

Is anyone here familiar with this bug? I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

// Server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const db = require("./db");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

// Use the cors middleware to enable CORS for your server
const corsOptions = {
  origin: process.env.CLIENT_ORIGIN, // Frontend address
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(cookieParser());

const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const favoritesRouter = require("./routes/favorites");

db.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("MySQL Connected...");
  }
});

// Parse URL-encoded bodies (as sent by HTML forms)
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/favorites", favoritesRouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server started");
});
```

// authController.js

```
exports.login = (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [email], (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" }); // Handle the database error
    }

    if (result.length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "User not found" });
      // Handle no users were found
    }

    const user = result[0];
    const passswordFromDb = user.password;

    bcrypt.compare(password, passswordFromDb).then((match) => {
      if (!match) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Incorrect password" });
      } else {
        const accessToken = createToken(user);

        res.cookie("access-token", accessToken, {
          maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 1000,
          secure: true,
          sameSite: "None",
        });

        return res.status(200).json({ message: "logged in" });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

// LogIn.js

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/auth/login`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(formData),
          credentials: "include",
        }
      );

      const responseData = await response.json();
      alert(responseData.message);

      if (response.ok) {
        const accessTokenCookie = document.cookie
          .split("; ")
          .find((cookie) => cookie.startsWith("access-token="));

        if (accessTokenCookie) {
          const accessToken = accessTokenCookie.replace("access-token=", "");
          const decodedCookie = jwt(accessToken);

          ctx.setUser({
            id: decodedCookie.id,
            email: decodedCookie.email,
            username: decodedCookie.username,
          });
          navigate("/");
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Login failed");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error:", err);
    }
  };
```

I tried Googling to figure out what might be causing the cookies to disappear but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but I can't see the code, where you set the cookie in the front end.